# What is 'socket' parameters in io.on()

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm learning Socket.io with node js ,express

In this code :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Log !');
});
```

What it's use the parameters **socket** in this function ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `socket` parameter gives you information about the connected client, such as the unique `socket.id` which will help you send events to that specific `socket`,  you can see in what rooms the `socket` is in, you can get information about the browser and more, you can inspect it with `console.log(socket)` and see a lot of information that you can use